# How to debug the procedure error `Must declare the table variable "@table1"`

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROC AllRowsAndagain
@table1 NVARCHAR(128)

AS
BEGIN
  select count(*) FROM @table1  
END;
```

I am getting this error -

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AllRowsAndagain11, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Must declare the table variable "@table1".

I want to pass the tablename as a parameter here

Comment: you are trying to query the `@table1` variable. What are you trying to achieve? Count the number of rows in a particular table and store it `@table1` variable or you want to pass the table name as a parameter into your procedure?

Comment: I want to pass the table name as a parameter in the procedure

Comment: You can't; a table (object)  name must be a literal, you can't replace it with a variable. This sounds like an XY problem, what is the problem you're actually trying to solve here? (You could do this with dynamic SQL, but I suspect that you have a different problem you actually need to solve.)

Comment: You can't parameterize objects without using dynamic sql. Whenever I see procedures like this I have to ask what you are really trying to solve because it is almost always an indication of a process not designed well.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a variable to replace the name of a table. You would need to use dynamic code for that. Fortunately, there's a more efficient way to retrieve the row count from any table.

```
CREATE PROC AllRowsAndagain
(
  @table1 NVARCHAR(128)
)
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT SUM(row_count) AS row_count
  FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
  WHERE OBJECT_NAME( object_id) = @table1
  AND index_id IN (0,1);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is it possible to have multiple select statements in this and Union them all?

Comment: Yes. Or you could use IN to have a single SELECT.

Comment: Can you please show me an example with IN on top of this proc?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am aware of how IN works, but what i wanted was if i need to use another table say TABLE2 and have another select from this TABLE2, can i have both these two selects staments in single proc under BEGIN and END?

Comment: Are you trying to solve the first problem from your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113752/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-and-pass-on-multiple-tables-and-get-the-output-b

Comment: Yes, correct, i am tried to have multiple select statements inside a single proc

Answer (score 2):

Like many have hinted in the comments you will need to use dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL however can be unsafe and you should try and avoid using it.

To answer your question you would need to use something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AllRowsAndagain
    @table1 NVARCHAR(128)

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SafeTableName AS NVARCHAR(128)

    SELECT @SafeTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table1

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select count(*) from ' + @SafeTableName + ';'

    EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

Checking the table against INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES makes your dynamic sql a lot safer. As it will only execute the dynamic statement if a table has been passed as the variable and not some malicious statement.

Comment: You're missing the data type for your parameter (but otherwise +1).

Comment: Just added the datatype! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for this and it looks clean, is there a way we can append multiple select statements to this dynamic sql proc?

Comment: +' union ' + ' select * from' + @SafeTableName  
 
i tried appending with the select statement but its giving me error, any help?

Comment: did you remove the semi colon from the end of the select statement?

Comment: DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select count(*) from ' + SafeTableName + 'union select * from ' + SafeTableName should just be able to do that if that's what you want.

Comment: and obviously the @ symbol in front of the SafeTableName variable. Wouldn't let me add more than one at symbol

Comment: Using `union` to return the row count and rows requires that both queries return the same number of columns and that the column datatypes are compatible. A stored procedure can return multiple recordsets, so there is no need to combine the queries.

Answer (score -3):

Your problem is that you are trying to count the number of rows in a string variable.
Seems a bit OTT but here you are.......

```
CREATE PROC AllRowsAndagain
@table1 NVARCHAR(128)

AS
BEGIN
  --DECLARE A VARIABLE TO HOLD THE STATEMENT
  DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(1024);

  --BUILD THGE STATMENT USING THE TABLE NAME YOU PASS IN
  SET @Statement = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', @table1, ';');
  --ONLY RUN FIRST COMMAND
  SET @Statement = SUBSTRING(@Statement, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @Statement));
  --RUN THE SQL
  exec sp_executesql @Statement;
END;
```

Comment: Do you know Little Bobby Tables?

Comment: I am not aware of little bobby tables, what are they? Can i have multiple select statements in this as well? like multiple SET statements?

Comment: LOL. http://bobby-tables.com/ The problem is that your code is wide open to sql injection. If I pass you the value "sys.tables;drop table Customers;" guess what happens to your Customers table?

Comment: How did this get an upvote, and why..? Injection isn't something that should be praised.

Comment: Understood - humblist apologies....I will flagellate myself later.
I took another approach by only executing the first statment.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: The real benefit of `QUOTENAME` , @HABO , is that it'll significantly lower the exposure to injection (when used correctly).